# Crawler que detecte mudanças em uma página e salve screenshots

Tags: python

Como fazer um crawler que permita listar todos os anúncios colocados num site como o custojusto.pt (por exemplo, na parte da mobília http://www.custojusto.pt/porto/moveis-decoracao?ca=5_s&th=1&q=&cg=5120&w=1) e que marcasse a hora em que o classificado aparecesse assim como a hora (aproximada a que ele desaparece) e que ao detectar alteração tire screenshot?

Comment: Pessoal, editei a questão dele para parecer menos 'questão pessoal'. Ela esta(va) mal redigida, mas não é uma questão absolutamente ruim. Acham que ela precisa melhorar mais ainda?

Comment: A pergunta está ruim, mas salvável. Seria bom ele melhorar o que ele precisa mais especificamente.

Answer (score 4):

**`phantomjs` é perfeito para isso**. Ele não é em python, mas é relativamente trivial para tarefas como essas e exige apenas que saiba javascript. Uma das principais vantagens é que ele tem recursos avançados que nenhum outro crawler que não interpreta javascript nem tem uma engine completa poderia fazer

Ele usa uma engine de um navegador WebKit (equivalente ao Google Chrome) e tem uma função específica para tirar screenshots. Com isso, você teria que fazer ele acessar a página e caso ela seja em ajax, só adicionar um evento que percebe que algo foi mudado, e se a página não carrega em ajax, teria que acessar a página de tempos e tempos e comparar com a página anterior, e então reparar as diferenças.

Aqui, [um exemplo de como acessar uma página e tirar um screenshot dela](http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html) :

**Arquivo github.js**

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://github.com/', function() {
   page.render('github.png');
  phantom.exit();
});
```

Então execute o arquivo por linha de comando com comando

> phantomjs github.js

Comment: Tenho alguns serviços no meu trabalho que utilizam o `phantomjs` e ele serve muito bem aos nossos propósitos. Você usa javascript para programar alguns procedimentos, não é muito trivial mas dá pra fazer muita coisa legal!

Comment: `phantomjs` para coisas **simples** é trivial. Agora tem coisas com ele, que são complicadas por causa dos bugs e da diferença de conceito entre contexto da página e contexto do `phantomjs`. Screenshot nesse caso ele é bem fácil de fazer e em poucas linhas

Comment: ghost.py (http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/) e um fork do phantom.js feito em python, ele basicamente usa o modulo webkit do qt

Comment: @tovmeod Posta como resposta. Se ele usa o Webkit é tão boa solução quanto o `phanthomjs`. Talvez outras pessoas também possam sugerir equivalentes em outras linguagens.

Answer (score 2):

Pra crawler você pode usar o [Scrapy](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/overview.html).

Answer (score 1):

Eu ja usei o [Ghost.py](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/). Ele é um fork do phantom de quando decidiram não suportar mais python e como o nome sugere e uma lib para quem esta usando python.

Internamente ele usa o módulo webkit do qt. Pode não ser a coisa mais rápida do mundo, mas ele executa js, abre iframes, baixa imagens e se comporta como um browser - ou pelo menos tenta - diferente de soluções como mechanize ou requests+beautifulsoup

Ele tem como dependência o PyQt ou PySide. Eu tive dor de cabeça para instalar pyside mas eventualmente funciona bem.

Eu so tropecei em um bug que e na verdade do modulo webkit do qt, que de vez em quando dava pau no meu processo inteiro, eu dei a volta por cima disso usando o modulo multiprocessing do python, se terminasse o processo por quanquer motivo nao parava o meu programa inteiro.

Homepage: http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/

Codigo fonte: https://github.com/jeanphix/Ghost.py